# Extract img ALT attribute from a link

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been trying to extract data from a alt="" string, but I keep getting it wrong.

The website is: https://www.morningstar.pt/pt/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000ZK96&tab=2

and the data is the morningstar rating, which currently is 2 (and I want it to refresh automatically).
The problem is that this is not expressed as text but as an image.
The lines are:

```
     td class="value text">
     img class="starsImg" src="https://www.morningstar.pt/includes/images/2stars.gif" alt="2 star">
```

I want to extract the "2 star", but have failed for hours with a lot of different approaches...
My code is currently as following (still incomplete):

```
Sub Get_Web_Data()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim rating As Variant

website = "https://www.morningstar.pt/pt/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000ZK96&tab=2"

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

request.Open "GET", website, False

request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

request.send

response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

html.body.innerHTML = response

rating = html.getElementsByClassName("value text")       --------> Incomplete

Range("A1").Value = rating

End Sub
```

Do you have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following approach to fetch the required rating from that webpage:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetData()
    Const website = "https://www.morningstar.pt/pt/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000ZK96&tab=2"
    Dim oHttp As Object, Html As HTMLDocument, rating As String
    
    Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument

    With oHttp
        .Open "GET", website, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        rating = Html.getElementsByClassName("starsImg")(0).alt
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = rating
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much for your help!!